# Compression Filter in ASP.NET MVC4 causes a content length of 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, compression

I'm using the CompressFilter attribute (below) on the output of a JsonNetResult (also below), everything works correctly until I apply the CompressFilter attribute to my controller method and then I get a 0 content length in the response. Stepping through the code everything looks ok, I hit the response.Write in the JsonNetResult with a valid string.
Does anyone have any idea how I can go about figuring out what's wrong? I'm stumped

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class CompressFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string[] supported = {"gzip", "deflate"};

        IEnumerable<string> preferredOrder = new AcceptList(request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"], supported);

        var preferred = preferredOrder.FirstOrDefault();

        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        switch (preferred)
        {
            case "gzip":
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                break;

            case "deflate":
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                break;

            case "identity":
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class AcceptList : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> encodings;
    private readonly Regex parser = new Regex(@"(?<name>[^;,\r\n]+)(?:;q=(?<value>[\d.]+))?", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public AcceptList(string acceptHeaderValue, IEnumerable<string> supportedEncodings)
    {
        var accepts = new List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptHeaderValue))
        {
            var matches = parser.Matches(acceptHeaderValue);

            var values = from Match v in matches
                where v.Success
                select new
                {
                    Name = v.Groups["name"].Value, v.Groups["value"].Value
                };

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (value.Name == "*")
                {
                    foreach (var encoding in supportedEncodings)
                    {
                        if (!accepts.Where(a => a.Key.ToUpperInvariant() == encoding.ToUpperInvariant()).Any())
                        {
                            accepts.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>(encoding, 1.0f));
                        }
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                var desired = 1.0f;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Value))
                {
                    float.TryParse(value.Value, out desired);
                }

                if (desired == 0.0f)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                accepts.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>(value.Name, desired));
            }
        }

        encodings = from a in accepts
            where supportedEncodings.Where(se => se.ToUpperInvariant() == a.Key.ToUpperInvariant()).Any() || a.Key.ToUpperInvariant() == "IDENTITY"
            orderby a.Value descending
            select a.Key;
    }

    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return encodings.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable) encodings).GetEnumerator();
    }
}


public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType) ? ContentType : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        if (Data == null)
            return;

        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented, DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat };
        var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, jsonSerializerSettings);
        response.Write(serializedObject);
    }
}
```